# why is this for loop taking so long?

Tags: c++

the for loop:

```
//for testing, this is usually a value of about 27
int test = level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice].size();

for (int i = 0; i < level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice].size(); i++)
{
    //adds the correct nodes to the search
    search.push_back(level.Nodes()[level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice][i]].Index());
}
```

and it's a 64 bit system.

I'm getting very strange results for the integer 'i' when debugging. it should be initialized to 0 but for some reason it's a very very high number which in turn means that the for loop is not executing.

Comment: Don't show us what the loop "essentially" is -- show us the actual code.

Comment: You should show more code, and tell us about your platform (32 or 64 bits) and system!

Comment: that loop will be just fine. The "real" loop will be the problem.

Comment: Actually, it's a `vector::size_type`.

Comment: "assume" and "essentially" or no good. If your code does not work and you have no clue why, show us the actual code.

Comment: Note that showing the actual code may include too much extraneous information. What is needed is a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/)–a complete, concise sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Your updated code still does not show the problem. Why is `test` relevant? Why do have the impression that `i` is bad?

Comment: where and how are you printing/viewing i to see this value?

Comment: Tbh, this question is pointless without more input / code / reproducable testcase.

Comment: has this question been unclosed? I'm confused, it just told me it was closed because it wasn't a good question.

Comment: I have the impression that i is bad because I set up a breakpoint and it showed it to have the value of a huge number

Comment: @SirYakalot: it was closed, and then we reopened it because you added actual code, making this an actual question.  See the [section in the faq about closing](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).  Unfortunately, you didn't add enough to actually diagnose the problem.

Comment: well i don't know what the actually problem is, surely you don't want to see all my code. there is a lot of it. why do I get the feeling I'm being told off for posting this?

Comment: @outis well i've been shouted at for showing minimal test case, and the actual code. Seems there's no right way of doing things today. sorry.

Comment: @SirYakalot: You can't close-to-vote multiple times. We *can't* help. The loop as you showed it is not buggy w.r.t. your problem of `i` being bad. I _am_ interested in helping, but I _can't_; it is not possible. So you have to help _us_ so _we_ can help _you_ better.

Comment: Can you look at the disassembly where it zeros `i` to see what's going on?

Comment: @SirYakalot: I smell that you checked the value of `i` before the loop. Put your breakpoint right after the opening brace of the loop body. If after the first run it is bad again, you are probably corrupting memory somehow or there is more invisible code that make `i` bad.

Comment: @SirYakalot: you haven't posted a minimal test case. A minimal test case is *complete* and *reproduces the problem* (neither of which describes the posted samples). Also, we're not shouting. We're barely chiding.

Comment: @SirYakalot:  We're not shouting at you -- there's nothing personal here.  But this question in it's original form was very poor.  We closed it because it was not a real question, and then you attempted to game the system by posting the exact same question again.  You've been part of SO for a while now, and I've answered your questions in the past.  I know that you know how the site works, you're just having a bad day.  Keep improving this question, and you'll get your problem figured out.

Comment: well the strange thing is that now that I check, none of the code after the loop is being run, and not only that, but sometimes the code in the loop seems to trigger a breakpoint i placed there, but the breakpoint i placed just before it doesn't trigger. Like some bits of code are being skipped.

Comment: @SirYakalot it may be possible that your debugger is showing an uninitialized value for `i` if your breakpoint is set on the line with the `for` loop. But as soon as you step into it the value will be properly assigned to `0` unless you have a really bad compiler. Your problem most certainly lies elsewhere.

Comment: @SirYakalot:  Are you running in Release mode?

Comment: @SirYakalot: Make sure you've turned optimization off and that you are doing a debug build.

Comment: @SirYakalot Is this optimized code?  You can't generally trust the debugger output with optimized code (and parts of the program may seem to disappear).  This is definitely the case with the VS debugger, but also with a lot of other debuggers.

Comment: no it's running in debug mode. and no it's just normal code. It really does seem to be jumping into the middle of the method. My computer did just have a hissy fit and almost crash. Could this be some corrupted data somewhere?

Comment: @SirYakalot:  Whoa.  Your recent edits have completely changed the nature of your question.  Please roll-back your edits and post a **new** question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> EDIT - just changed it so that it's just an int, now it gets a value
>   of -82938723047 or some such number. why on earth is this happening?
>   It's ruining my program!

You are almost certainly barking up the wrong tree.  The code:

```
for (int i = 0;
```

...initializes `i` to `0`, period.  If you're trying to spy its value in the debugger and the debugger says `i` has a value that looks like uninitialized, garbage data, then you are probably looking at `i` either before or after `i` has entered scope and been initialized.  For example, in MSVC if you examine `i` before you enter the loop for the very first time, it will often have garbage data.

These are not the droids you're looking for.  Move along.

Much more likely is this code:

```
level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice].size()
```

This is probably not doing what you think it's doing.

By the way, if the type of `level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice]` is a `vector` of some kind, I'd prefer that you use a `for` loop constructed like this.

```
/*psudocode*/ for( vector::iterator it = v.begin(), it_end = v.end(); it != it_end; ++it )
```

If you don't need the index of the element you're trying to access, then why refer to it?  You're just introducing another potential failure point in your code.