# why is this block of code taking so long?

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice].size(); i++)
{
    //adds the correct nodes to the search
    search.push_back(level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice][i]);
}
```

and it's a 64 bit system.

the program is taking about 30 seconds to execute one pass of the loop. Is there a reason why this is happeneing? I'm not sure what info you guys will need but ask and i'll get it for you.

search is a vector of integers and pathLookupVectors is a vector of vectors of vectors of ints.

search usually ends up being populated by an average of 27 integers but can be a little higher or as low as one.

I did notice I'm passing pathLookupVectors by value. could that be the problem?

Comment: How many iterations of the loop are executed?

Comment: around 27, but it varies from 1 to maybe 35.

Comment: How big is `search`? What do PathLookupVectors and Nodes return and how are they implemented? What does .Index() do? What does the profiler tell you?

Comment: Can you provide us some more data about the LookUpVectors size, how the search function works, etc??? Without that, this question is meaningless

Comment: Show us the declaration of `PathLookupVectors()`

Comment: Can you narrow it down? Are `Nodes()`, `PathLookupVectors()`, and `Index()` all fast? (Conceivably if you store a reference to `level.PathLookupVectors()[...][...]` before the loop, instead of calling it over and over, it could help... as long as those methods don't have side effects!)

Comment: How long does one call to `level.PathLookupVectors()` take? For each iteration of the loop that call is being made twice so that might be your bottleneck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is this for loop taking so long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244152/why-is-this-for-loop-taking-so-long)

Comment: Have you learned nothing from your other question today, i.e. the comment section? We really can't soothsay what's in your slow loop. We'd need more insight. Maybe it is so slow because you are on a slow machine. Maybe you are on a fast machine that is currently quite busy. Maybe the number of iterations is too high. Maybe you are `push_back`ing megabytes and gigabytes of data. Maybe you have overloaded some `operator[]` and inside it is doing something really slow. Maybe the call to `PathLookupVectors()` is slow because it returns large datasets and you are doing it each loop. Maybe ...

Comment: @BoPersson: The question you've linked to was edited to be completely different from what it originally was.  The edits of the other question should be rolled back, which would make this not a dupe.

Comment: I did roll it back, and phresnell, go easy! I'm trying to give the relevant info but I'm learning what that is as I go. I haven't been doing this that long. also I'm not at my computer and trying to make the relevant edits on an iPhone! but thank you for your help, I don't know what I'd do without this site!

Comment: @SirYakalot: be conscious about what you will be posting, and try to think about the code as if you were a potential answerer; think "Could I judge from this what would be taking so long? Which external dependencies are there?". When you try to stuff a minimal, self contained testcase, you often (not always) find the root-cause of your problem yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to say without seeing all the relevant code, but I suspect that:

```
level.PathLookupVectors()
```

...might return a `vector` of some kind by-value, rather than by-pointer- or by-reference.  This is just a guess, but if this is so, you could be creating temporary copies of the whole vector, and then modifying that.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
correct_type &cache = level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice];
for (unsigned int i = 0, size = cache.size(); i < size; i++)
{
    //adds the correct nodes to the search
    search.push_back(cache[i]);
}
```

This is to avoid recomputing `level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice]` many times.

Comment: I'm not at my computer but I strongly suspect you are right about this. I'll check asap

Answer (score 0):

This statement is executing **twice** on each iteration. On the conditional of the for-statement:

```
level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice].size()
```

And in the body of the for-statement:

```
search.push_back(level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice][i]);
```

That's a NO NO!

**EDIT:** This is totally unnecessary because:

```
level.PathLookupVectors()[globalNodePositionIndex][globalNodeChoice]
```

never changes. What you should do is assign it to a variable, and the use the variable in the for-loop instead of calculating it each time.

Comment: interesting! I'm fairly new at this. how would I alter it to not do this then?

Comment: does the compiler not inline something like this?

Comment: @SirYakalot no, it's calculating it each time

Comment: how can you tell what's going to be inlined and what's not?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `search` is huge and your allocating a large vector over and over.  Try using `std::vector::reserve` before allocating.

If it's really that big, you probably should not be using a vector to build it.  Build it with another data structure and they copy it back into the vector.

If you need indexed access while building, use a `std::deque`.  If you don't then just use a `std::list`.